# Ubercart recurring issue

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I'm using uc_recurring module in my Drupal based site. I just can't get on with it:
In the cart I want to make possible of subscribing for the products. The customer can subscribe for the products (weekly, biweekly, monthly, semianually, etc) while buying them, for he can get discounts through subscription(12%, 9%, 6%, 3%) respectively. As far as the customer is subscribed for some type of products, on that point when the appointed day comes, transaction should occur via PayPal gateway and a certain amount of money needs to be charged from the subscriber's account, and send them notifications.

How can I manage subscription and unsubscription?

Comment: is there anybody who knows Drupal in stack?

Comment: There are a few knowledgable Drupal users here but this site is for programming questions so I doubt you'll get a flood of responses as your question is not about programming. drupal.stackexchange.com would be more suitable for this question I think.

Comment: I've also added the same issue on the drupal.stackexchange.com, but no one has answered.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's quite possible that nobody who knows the answer has come across your question yet. Cross-posting questions is pretty strongly discouraged by the moderators...I wouldn't be surprised to see this closed if you've posted a duplicate on another stackexchange site :/ Have you tried opening an account on drupal.org itself and asking on the forums there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking: are you having trouble setting up the various subscription options? (weekly, biweekly, monthly, etc.)

Have you looked at the demo? If not, it's at http://recurring.sites.univate.com.au/ .

The ReadMe for the module says you need to do this:

> Step 2: Setup Recurring Payments:
>   (This step can be skipped if you do not accept payments on site and you do not
>   have the uc_payment module enabled)
>
> > - Requirement: Installed and setup payment gateways in ubercart.
> > - Go to:
> >       "Store administration" -> "Configuration" -> "Payment Settings" -> "Edit" -> "Recurring payments"
> > - Select payment methods that should be allows to process recurring payments,
> >       only the methods selected will be shown on the checkout page when a order
> >       includes a recurring product.
>
> Step 3: Enable a module that triggers recurring payments on certain events.
>
> > - Recurring Products (uc_recurring_product) - product specific recurring fees (e.g. subscriptions)
> > - Recurring Order (uc_recurring_order) - entire order is recurring.

Are you able to get to the Payment Settings - Recurring Payments page?

Have you also installed and enabled either Recurring Products or Recurring Order?

Are you using Drupal 7 or Drupal 6?